# What does “Empedocles’ sandal” mean in terms of English usage?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

I first heard the expression “Empedocles’ sandal” a long time ago without knowing what it referred to. It seems to derive from the legend of the ancient Greek philosopher Empedocles (who was supposedly given to wearing scarlet clothes, a crown decorated with laurel flowers, a golden belt and bronze sandals).

The legend describes Empedocles’ inadvertent suicide — the outcome of jumping into a volcano to demonstrate his immortality. The volcano, however, only threw back one of his sandals.

The phrase has occasionally returned to haunt me, but I don’t know what it signifies to English speakers, or in what situations it might be used as the basis for a quip or allusion. Can you shed any light on its usage?

Comment: I never heard this before. I can't say it's very common, but it sure is interesting!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empedocles) mentions the following:

> Diogenes Laërtius records the legend that he died by throwing himself into an active volcano (Mount Etna in Sicily), so that people would believe his body had vanished and he had turned into an immortal god; the volcano, however, threw back one of his bronze sandals, revealing the deceit.

Although I cannot say I ever heard the expression used, I would assume, based on this description, that *Empedocles’ sandal* is the sign that gives away a deceit. I imagine it could be used in a sentence like this:

> The credit card bill that he carelessly had left on the table for his wife to find turned out to be his Empedocles’ sandal; it revealed he had spent the weekend in a Paris hotel instead of working overtime at the office.

Comment: [_Diogenes Laërtius, viii. 69_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0258%3Abook%3D8%3Achapter%3D2).

Comment: It would be used, then, much like the more familiar phrase "his *Achilles' heel*" - meaning one's weak spot - but with the meaning of irrefutable evidence of an attempt to deceive. I never heard this phrase before, either.

Comment: @medica yes, I was reminded of the Achilles' heel as well.

Comment: @Amphiteoth. Thank you for providing me a valuable source. Since I didn't know anything about Empedocles, it's very informative, and will give me a clue to this phrase.

Comment: @YoichiOishi You're welcome! The reference is included in a note from the article in the answer, just making it convenient... His taste for magma-safe apparel had a heavy impact, on history.

Comment: I've never heard the expression either; but I instinctively want to add a determiner to it, just like with _Achilles’ heel_, to make it “turned out to be _his_ Empedocles’ sandal”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: actually, I was somehow sure I _had_ added that in my made up quote! It somehow _does_ sound more natural with it, so I added it after all :)

Comment: I hadn't heard of Empedocles' sandal before either. It reminds me of the expression "smoking gun."

Comment: I don't think Achilles' Heel quite works - the clue that reveals X has done bad stuff is not his weakness, but might reveal his weakness.

Comment: @Oldcat nobody suggested the _meaning_ was the same, just the usage :)

Comment: I suppose it is true, almost physiologically, that Empedocles’ sandal reveals Achilles’ heel (assuming that Achilles is wearing Empedocles’ sandals at the time, of course). :-D

Comment: @oerkelens - your use for revealing a deceit seems pretty sound, but I suggest the phrase might also be used to reveal a *self-deception*... since obviously throwing oneself into a volcano isn't something a person does for a cynical scam, they do so because they sincerely believe it.  So, perhaps "The letter turned out to be his Empedocle's sandal, he had based all his plans that the offer would be made, and now it had fallen through".  Or something like that - the physical evidence that some sincerely held belief was actually false.

Answer (score 2):

According to Deleuze, the physical, lowly sandal (worn on the foot, in contact with the ground) represents the antithesis of the divine, and hence is a symbol of someone's material, bodily, physical existence. "To the wings of the Platonic soul the sandal of Empedocles is opposed, proving that he was of the earth, under the earth, and autochthonous." (*Logic of Self*, 128). See *The Priority of Events: Deleuze's Logic of Sense*, By Sean Bowden, 2011, p 16.

The sandal is proof that Empedocles is not divine, and thus is a symbol of the something physical, tangible, quotidian. One example of the metaphorical use is "On the contrary, like Empedocles' sandal, [Brecht's] poems can be treated as a very tangible, earthly, concrete legacy." (*Empedocles' Shoe: Essays on Brecht's Poetry*, edited Tom Kuhn and Karen Leeder, p 4.)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer gives a convincing explanation of what this expression *should* mean if it is used.

But a very important point that I think should be emphasized is that **this expression is *almost never* used.**

So the answer the actual question,

> I don’t know what it signifies to English speakers, or in what
> situations it might be used as the basis for a quip or allusion. Can
> you shed any light on its usage?

is that an overwhelming majority of English speakers, even well-educated ones, would **not have heard of this expression and would have no idea what you are talking about.** Therefore, you can use it only in situations in which you happen to know that your audience is familiar with the story from which the expression originates (for example, because you have personally first told your audience the story). Once you know you have such an audience, you can refer to [the accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/215804/155553) and all the comments here as to in what context it would be appropriate to use the expression.

### Discussion

**Lack of familiarity in general educated public**

First of all, as you could see from all the answers and the comments, no one here has heard of it—and we are talking about a group of English language enthusiasts.

Secondly, the expression is not found any of the dictionaries I looked, including the OED and *Merriam-Webster.* (I tried six forms of it: *Empedocles’ sandal, Empedocles’s sandal,* *Empedocles sandal,* and the same three with *shoe* instead of *sandal*) In contrast, *Achilles' heel* is in all of them.

Third, the expression (in any of the six forms) is not found on [Google Books NGram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/).

Fourth, it is not found (in any of the six forms) in either the [*Corpus of Contemporary American English*](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (COCA) or the [*British National Corpus*](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) (BNC).

**Better familiarity in other languages**

The phrase seems better known in other languages. The German Wikipedia, for example, has [this entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_griechischer_Phrasen/Tau#%CF%84%E1%BD%B0_%CF%83%CE%AC%CE%BD%CE%B4%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B1_%CF%84%CE%BF%E1%BF%A6_%E1%BC%98%CE%BC%CF%80%CE%B5%CE%B4%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%AD%CE%BF%CF%82):

> The sandals of Empedocles
>  In Greek: τα σάνδαλα του Εμπεδοκλή (ta
> sandala tou Embedokli)
>
> In Diogenes Laertius' account of the death of the philosopher
> Empedocles, it is said that Empedocles chose to reinforce the
> widespread belief that he had become a god by throwing himself into
> Mount Etna in order to leave no trace on Earth. However, the crater
> spat out his sandals.
>
> The poet Friedrich Hölderlin explores this figure between "excess" and
> "nobility" in his play "The Death of Empedocles," for which he
> developed three versions. He also wrote the following poem:
>
> *You seek life, seek it, and it wells up and shines
>  A divine fire deep from the earth to you,
>  And in tremulous desire
>  You cast
> yourself down into the flames of Etna.*
>
> Bertolt Brecht uses this legend as a fable to criticize the cult of
> leadership in his didactic poem "The Shoe of Empedocles."
>
> "The Sandals of Empedocles" is also the title of a book by Norbert
> Wokart, subtitled "A Small Philosophy of Everyday Life."

**Presence in some English-language sources**

On the other hand, if one searches google books, one does find some hits. (I don't know why these hits didn't register in the NGram Viewer.) Here are some of them.

From ***Empedocles' Shoe:** Essays on Brecht's Poetry,*  T. Kuhn and K. Leeder, eds. (Methuen, London, 2002).

> It is not the purpose of this volume to win uncritical readers for
> Brecht. On the contrary, like **Empedocles' sandal,** his poems can be
> treated as a very tangible, earthly, concrete legacy.

From G. Flood, *Religion and the Philosophy of Life* (Oxford Univ. Press, Oxford, 2019), pp. 310-311.

> This never-ending process, the constant renewal of life itself in the
> present, the coming to actuality of the virtual and its dissolving
> back into the virtual, to use Bergson’s terminology, is a horizontal
> philosophy, although Deleuze himself does use the metaphor of
> verticality to present a typology of philosophy. On the one hand, we
> have an emphasis on height, that we see in Plato for example, the
> height where Apollo lives, in contrast to which we have the depth of
> Dionysus and the pre-Socratic philosophers of fire and water. The
> Platonic ideal of height is linked to asceticism in that the ascetic
> rises up, thereby becoming purified in a process that Deleuze refers
> to as ‘ascensional psychism’ and that we find innumerable examples of
> in the history of religions. In contrast, **Empedocles jumps into
> Mount Etna and the volcano spews out his lead sandal.** Empedocles is
> a philosopher of the depth for Deleuze, a philosopher of the earth,
> not the height:
>
> *To the wings of the Platonic soul the sandal of Empedocles is opposed, proving that he was of the earth, under the earth, and
> autochthonous. To the beating of the Platonic wings there corresponds
> a pre-Socratic subversion. The encased depths strike Nietzsche as the
> real orientation of philosophy, the pre-Socratic discovery that must
> be revived in a philosophy of the future, with all the forces of a
> life which is also a thought, and of a language which is also a body.*
>
> But the contrast between Plato’s wings and Empedocles’ sandal is
> somewhat of an illusion for Deleuze because in truth there is no
> height or depth. What we have is surface and the philosophers of
> surface par excellence are the Stoics and the Cynics who wrap
> themselves up in ‘the surface, the carpet and the mantle’.

From C. Fuentes, *The Great Latin American Novel* (Dalkey Archive Press,Victoria, Tx, 2016), translated from Spanish.

> To be a born survivor means that nothing dies completely, and that
> Roberto Soto Gariglietti is a mirror image of both the Mexican comic
> and the Sicilian philosopher, to the extent that both are part of the
> human tragic-comedy. After all, it is funny that **Empedocles** ends
> his life by leaping into the crater of the volcano Etna, which gave
> birth to the celebrated couplet:
>
> *Poor Empedocles, that restless soul,
>  Jumped into Etna, and was roasted whole.*
>
> Other versions say that **Empedocles** was hurled up by the volcano to
> a heavenly Elysium; others that he fooled the whole world and only
> left a **sandal** atop the volcano to make them believe in the myth of
> his death.
>
> …
>
> You, “hypocrite reader, my likeness, my brother,” said Baudelaire in
> order to say what is always known in poetic art but rarely said in
> narrative art. I direct myself to you, reader; without you, I do not
> exist, the book becomes an object lying in wait for the next reader to
> revive it, to save it from the volcano, to pick up **Empedocles’s
> sandal.**

From H. Sidebottom, *The Burning Road* (Bonnier Publishing Fiction, 2021). The author of this historical thriller is a Tutor in Ancient History at St. Benet's Hall, Oxford, and lecturer at Lincoln College.

> If the mountain accepted their offerings the omens were good, but if
> it rejected them, cast them out like **Empedocles' sandal,** the
> portent could not be more dire.

### Conclusion

As you can see (by looking at the examples above as well as at the [other hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Empedocles+sandal%22&tbm=bks&ei=VXGYZPGfOtSr5NoPoKiEiAk&ved=0ahUKEwixnve68d7_AhXUFVkFHSAUAZEQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22Empedocles+sandal%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQvANY7wRggApoAHAAeACAAckBiAG8BJIBBTAuMi4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) on google books), when the phrase *Empedocles' sandal/shoe* is invoked in English, usually one is discussing non-English language authors, or else is invoked by people who are specialists in ancient history.